# SQL query to display products that have been sold in one country and not another

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause, having-clause

Display the supplier names that have products sold to Mexico but not Spain

```
SELECT s.CompanyName 
FROM  OrderSupplier.Suppliers s
WHERE Country <> 'Spain' 
(SELECT p.Id 
FROM OrderSupplier.Suppliers s
JOIN OrderSupplier.Products p ON s.Id = p.SupplierId 
JOIN OrderSupplier.OrderItem oi ON p.Id = oi.ProductId 
JOIN OrderSupplier.Orders o ON oi.OrderId = o.Id 
JOIN OrderSupplier.Customers c ON o.CustomerId = c.Id
WHERE c.country = 'Mexico')
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question here? What's wrong with the attempt you've made?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. (This question should be all text.)

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a series of joins to bring all customers of each supplier, then aggregation:

```
SELECT s.Id 
FROM OrderSupplier.Suppliers s
INNER JOIN OrderSupplier.Products p ON s.Id = p.SupplierId 
INNER JOIN OrderSupplier.OrderItem oi ON p.Id = oi.ProductId 
INNER JOIN OrderSupplier.Orders o ON oi.OrderId = o.Id 
INNER JOIN OrderSupplier.Customers c ON o.CustomerId = c.Id
WHERE c.country IN ('Mexico', 'Spain')
GROUP BY s.Id
HAVING MIN(c.country) = MAX(c.country) and MIN(c.country) = 'Mexico'
```

The `WHERE` clause filters on customers in Spain *or* Mexico. The `HAVING` clause then ensures that only Mexico was found.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you so much for this answer! Can you please explain the use of MIN and MAX? I am a new learner of SQL and dont quite understand that part

Comment: Hey  thank you for the input really appreciate it. Can you please delete your previous comment with my name if thats ok? As this is for a uni assignment and I dont think I was meant to post here....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
;with
mex_cte as (
    select distinct s.id supplier_id
    from OrderSupplier.Suppliers s
         join OrderSupplier.Products p ON s.Id = p.SupplierId 
         JOIN OrderSupplier.OrderItem oi ON p.Id = oi.ProductId 
         JOIN OrderSupplier.Orders o ON oi.OrderId = o.Id 
         JOIN OrderSupplier.Customers c ON o.CustomerId = c.Id
    WHERE c.country = 'Mexico'),
sp_cte as (
    select distinct s.id supplier_id
    from OrderSupplier.Suppliers s
         join OrderSupplier.Products p ON s.Id = p.SupplierId 
         JOIN OrderSupplier.OrderItem oi ON p.Id = oi.ProductId 
         JOIN OrderSupplier.Orders o ON oi.OrderId = o.Id 
         JOIN OrderSupplier.Customers c ON o.CustomerId = c.Id
    WHERE c.country = 'Spain')
select * from mex_cte
except
select * from sp_cte;
```

Comment: this answer seems much more understandable than the answer from @GMB, although technically you don't need to put each sql into a cte. also I'd recommend against using distinct for performance reasons.

Comment: I actually understand this one better! How would you do it without WITH or cte though?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
P.ProductName, 
S.Country
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN Suppliers S on S.Id = P.SupplierId
where S.Country = 'USA'
and P.ProductName NOT IN
(
Select P.ProductName 
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN Suppliers S on S.Id = P.SupplierId
where S.Country = 'France'
)
Group by P.ProductName, S.Country
```

This gives you the products that were sold in USA but not France.

Answer (score -3):

You should provide sample data and expected result but based on what you have provided you can achieve the result by using `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Provide a sample data or Fiddle